# Can weight of a body cause tipping (friction) about any point?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, weight

In a problem regarding below figure given body is tipping about point A. In textbooks the examples given always were tipping of body due to external force . Is it possible for a body to tipping due to its own weight?
Please clarify mathematically[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the CCW torque about point (A) produce by the force (P) is greater than the CW torque produced by gravity, then the rod will tip up from the surface of the incline.

Comment: Yes, I observed the tipping by experimenting with some objects.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if the coefficient of friction $\mu$ is greater than $\tan\theta$, the body won't slide, but could easily tip over, if the line of the weight falls outside the base, as in the diagram below.

[image]

Even for the $20^{\circ}$ angle, usually a body wouldn't slide, but if it were tall the tipping could still occur.